# Can unity psb importer leaves more space for each sprite?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can unity psb importer leaves more space for each sprite?
When unity imports a psb file, it generate a sprite for each layer, but the problem is, it leaves zero free space for them, it squeezes each sprites into a frame that fit perfectly, this might be good for saving ram, but if I draw more stuff in that layer, it will be cut out, and I will need to redo the rig! And, the auto geometry in skinning editor is not working properly because of this, some part of the sprite is not included! I have no idea why unity didn't notice this, or is it because there is something that I don't know?

Answer (score 0):

When you enter the Sprite Editor window, go to the tab on the upper left corner -> Sprite Editor

Here you can see how the importer spreads the layers.
If there's a specific image you want to have more space, simply click it and drag the bounds of the blue frame to expend it.

Do take notice that the position of the geometry is calculated from the bottom left corner of the this bounding frame, So any changes to its position will move the geometry (which *can* be fixed in the "Skinning editor" mode, but be aware of that).